# How create setting activity to appear half of the screen from bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want to make a setting activity like as shown in the image. What should be my logic to develop this kind of screen? Please help me, as I am new to android and I want this type of activity. I have tried many solution's but didn't found like the image I have shared with you.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: create bottom sheet with preference https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### best option is use [bottomSheet](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet/) lib for this.

---

***but you still want to do your self just do below way.***

[image]

create below method

```
public void openBottomSheet() {

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_emp_cov, null);
    Spinner spin1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spin1);
    Spinner spin2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spin2);
    ListView catList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItems);
    Button btnDone = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDone);

    final Dialog mBottomSheetDialog = new Dialog(RepActivity.this,
            R.style.MaterialDialogSheet);
    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
    mBottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    mBottomSheetDialog.show();

    spin1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(RepActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, items));
    spin2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(RepActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, items));

    catList.setAdapter(categoryListAdapter);

    btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

bottom_sheet_emp_cov layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_window"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_uninstall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Done" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="Select Zone:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="Select Region:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MaterialDialogSheet style

```
<style name="MaterialDialogSheet" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MaterialDialogSheetAnimation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MaterialDialogSheetAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>
    </style>
```

popup_show animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

popup_hide animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

firstly you need to use this theme for `SettingsActivity` to give it transparent background

```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent4" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

then in your activity you can set the width and height of it 
if you want it half of the screen 
you can set the height of it programmatically 
parent view all take all the screen space 
then create child layout 
and the the height of it

```
 contentView.getLayoutParams().height=screenheight/2;
```

Comment: Down voter could you please specify the reason of the negative vote??!!

Comment: Thank you @Tony for your quick response. I am thinking the same right now. I will try your solution, and let you know.

Comment: You are wlc, @AkhilGite tell me if u faced any problems

Comment: @AkhilGite have you solved your problem?

Comment: ya. I have used @Dhawal's soln. Its very easy. I tried your soln too, but comparatively his soln is better. Thank you.